# Instructions for flashing a phone or tablet device with Ubuntu fron

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a question.

Its possible to find instructions for flashing a phone or tablet device with Ubuntu for Sony Xperia T?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu touch is still in development and is not recommended for general use yet unless you are a developer or willing to use it as a test (accepting there may be bugs). Also currently during development the operating system is being written for new (unreleased) hardware and the Google nexus, with wider support to be rolled out later.

This being said some developers are working on the Xperia T. Many features are still a work in progress. [See this page for information on what does and doesn't work and how to install.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/mint)